# Percentage 10% of four other percentages

Tags: percentages

What is 10% of the four percentages together:

50% 70% 100% 100%

In other words, what is 10% of the above percentages added together to receive a total mark out of 10%?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean add?

To say 10% of 50% means 10% * 50%

However if you mean adding them, your answer is 32%

$\frac{0.5 + 0.7 + 1 + 1}{10}=0.32$